# laravel failed to open stream: No such file or directory error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I just moved a Laravel project from another directory and I am having this error and I don't know where I missed, everything was right.

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\bsms\vendor\composer/../infyomlabs/laravel-generator/src/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bsms\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\bsms\vendor\composer/../infyomlabs/laravel-generator/src/helpers.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\bsms\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Comment: Run following command (1)php artisan cache:clear (2)php artisan confg:cache (3) php artisan view:clear (4) composer dumpa

Comment: @Manisha Its composer dump-autoload

Comment: First conform all folder is move 100%?

Answer (score 16):

First, make sure you have set up composer properly via `composer install`.

Then, run these commands:

```
composer dump-autoload
composer update --no-scripts
composer update
```

---

- `composer install` It will just install all the dependencies as specified in the **composer.lock** file.
- `composer dump-autoload` It will clean up all compiled files and their paths.
- `composer update --no-scripts` It will Skips execution of scripts defined in **composer.json** file.
- `composer update` It will update your depencencies as they are specified in **composer.json** file.

Comment: Thank you @Udhav for this concise solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```